# Facebook Url Share content

Tags: facebook, sharing, facebook-social-plugins

It is very strange, that when I share my site url on facebook it shows me my designers name with it. I tried removing all meta tags from my html page, I removed all details of images but it still appears. I searched on facebook developers but couldn't find a solution. Please help me in this.
The url which I am sharing is [this](http://www.youffer.com/Download)

[image: http://www.youffer.com/Download]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OpenGraph Debugger to re-scrape your page's information manually:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Enter your url, and click on *Fetch new scrape information*. Voilá!